# Ruby: if condition inside each condition

Tags: ruby

I need to compare array element inside "each" condition as shown below:

```
a = ["config_left","mon_left","acc_left",lg_left..]
a.each { |x| 
  ff.div(:id, x).fireEvent("onmouseup")
  if x == 1   ##<<<<<<<<<<<<is this right? 
    Watir::Waiter::wait_until{ff.button(:id, "add").enabled?}
  else
    sleep 7
end
```

Is `x == 1` right? Tried with `x == "mon_left"` but even that doesn't work. Please help on it.

Comment: identation is civilized.

Comment: This is a really bad question. Grammar is wrong, the question is not clear. many variables/methods are given without notice.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should post a complete example - I had to fix at least 3 syntax errors in your question.

Second, what do you mean by "It doesn't work"? This works for me:

```
a = ["config_left","mon_left","acc_left","lg_left"]  
a.each_with_index do |x,i|  
  puts i if x == "mon_left"  
end
```

Third, you might want to use a.detect ... instead of each / if

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are talking about index:

```
some_array.each{ | element, index| 
   do_something if index == 1
}
```

So in your case

```
a = ["config_left","mon_left","acc_left", "lg_left"] 
a.each { |x, i| 
  ff.div(:id, x).fireEvent("onmouseup")
  if i == 1   
      Watir::Waiter::wait_until{ff.button(:id, "add").enabled?}
  else
      sleep 7
  end
}
```

Comment: You need `each_with_index`, not `each` to take `i` inside the block.

Comment: Hi,
Tried as you suggested but its

Comment: Hi, Tried as you suggested but not getting required output.
a.each { |x,i| 
ff.div(:id, x).fireEvent("onmouseup")
puts i
puts "#{i}"
if i == 1
Watir::Wait.wait_until{ff.button(:id, "jid-gen-btnTbarAdd-button").enabled?} 
else
sleep 7
end
}
With puts i the output is nil and with puts "#{i}" output is blank :(
I am very new to ruby so regret for the trouble!